# console.error: "fontFamily "Roboto_medium" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

When using import Native Base (as it comes) I have encountered trouble because of a Font error shown in screen. If you click dismiss it will disappear but the user can't be seeing that every time a Text gets loaded. ¿Is there a correct way to solve the font problem?

This [official](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html) documentation says to do this:

```
// At the top of your file
import { Font } from 'expo';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

// Later on in your component
async componentDidMount() {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'Roboto': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
    'Roboto_medium': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
    ...Ionicons.font,
  });
}
```

but it didn't work. This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, } from "react-native";
import { Button, Text } from 'native-base';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {

  render() {

        return (
                 <View>
                     <Button>
                       <Text>Click me!</Text>
                     </Button>
                  </View>
                )
   }
}
```

I expect the code to run smoothly but every time it loads the same error:

```
console.error: "fontFamily "Roboto_medium" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync."
__expoConsoleLog
    AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:95014:31
...................
...................
...................
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For newer Functional Components solved it like this**

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NativeBaseProvider, Text } from 'native-base';

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <View>
        <Text>Example Text</Text>
      </View>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  )
}
export default MyComponent;
```

**For older Functional Components solved it like this**

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'native-base';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

const MyComponent = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
    }))();
   }, [])

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Example Text</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
export default MyComponent;
```

**For Class Components solved it like this**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, } from "react-native";
import { Button, Text } from 'native-base';
import { Font } from 'expo';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    loading: true
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'Roboto': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      'Roboto_medium': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ...Ionicons.font,
    })
    this.setState({ loading: false })
  }

  render() {
       if (this.state.loading) {
         return (
           <View></View>
         );
       }
        return (
          <View>
            <Button>
              <Text>Click me!</Text>
            </Button>
          </View>
       )
   }
}
```

Comment: Even better, doing this you can use the font a lot easier: https://medium.com/@danielskripnik/how-to-add-and-remove-custom-fonts-in-react-native-b2830084b0e4

Comment: Nice recommendation, I'm using expo for now but this will help when I eject the project

Comment: can you tell how to do it via functional components?

Comment: I just learned some functional components and it can be solved by keeping the await function in useEffect hook.

Comment: `Error: The following APIs have moved to separate packages and importing them from the "expo" package is no longer supported: Font.` -- The answers below are up to date!

Comment: I'm using <NativeBaseProvider> in my main App.tsx but I also had to put it in each Custom Component for style (text bold etc.) to work. Is this right ? I thought <NativeBaseProvider> had to be only in App Root and all the children got affected

Comment: Yes I’ve tried removing it and it won’t work,  all chidren are not being affected. If this answer was useful please consider an upvote

Answer (score 9):

Native Base uses **Roboto_Medium** as a font for Title and some objects. **Roboto_Medium** is not a system font.

You can do either two things

1. Install and Load **Roboto_Medium** font in your codebase.
2. Edit existing **Native Base** core files

**1) Install and Load Roboto_Medium font in your codebase**
After installing Native Base, run these in terminal `expo install expo-font`.
After that Open your **App.js** file, add this two lines, 
`import * as Font from 'expo-font';`
`import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';`
After that include function **componentDidMount()**

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await Font.loadAsync({
     Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
     Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
     ...Ionicons.font,
  });
  this.setState({ isReady: true });
}
```

You must call **componentDidMount()** function. If you are using Class Component, then this can be called using *constuctor* method

```
constructor(){
   componentDidMount();
}
```

But, if you are using Functional Method, then you have manually call the **componentDidMount()** function.

**2) Edit existing Native Base core files** (Alternative) 
You have to edit core **Native Base** files. 
Location of File:

1. **commonColor.js** 
   *node_modules\native-base\dist\src\theme\variables* \ **commonColor.js**
2. **material.js** 
   *node_modules\native-base\dist\src\theme\variables* \ **material.js**
3. **platform.js** 
   *node_modules\native-base\dist\src\theme\variables* \ **platform.js** 
   In this files, find **"Roboto_Medium"** and replace it with **"Roboto"** or any other system default fonts.

But, as we have hardcoded the node_modules, with each update of Native Base, you have to again hard code the values again.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone still has this problem and is using functional components, i solved it like this:

```
 import * as Font from 'expo-font';


useEffect(() => {
(async () => await Font.loadAsync({
  Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
  Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
}))();
 }, [])
```